# The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later in backend login issue

Tags: magento2.3, login, backend

I am using magento 2.3. Particular backend admin user login does not working in particular system and laptop. "Error occur : The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later." I checked locked user permission and i checked table "oauth_token_request_log". But still error occured. New user also does not working in any system and laptop sometimes. I cleared all cache and reindex. But still same issue. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: did you try login using another browser?

Comment: I tired all browser firefox, chrome, opera, safari

Comment: what about customer login, is it working?

Comment: backend admin user, role - administrator. i created new user login to my client access. but client said , "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later in backend login issue". in laptop only. and created another user that is also same issue for my system and laptop also . i do what is the reason

Comment: Please reply , what is the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs due to Magento 2’s security system. Magento 2 will temporarily disable accounts that do not meet it’s password complexity requirements.

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'NewP@ssword'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'adminusername';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because of many reasons, one of the reason is,

"There is an alpha character and a numeric character in the admin password. This should be labeled a bug if the password is not validated during install with magento setup:install."

try to reset the password of your admin by clicking on "Forgot Your Password?"

[Click](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/you-did-not-sign-in-correctly-or-your-account-is-temporarily-disabled-magento-2.html) here for more reference

Comment: may be it is happen but my doubt is account disabled in sometimes only and some system and laptop. our client said , it is working in desktop system not in laptop. that is teh problem. our client said continuesly last 2days. what i will do? any reason for that. How to solve this issue.